# What are the prerequisites for reading SGA 1?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, book-recommendation

My question concerns, basically, scheme theory. If there is someone who has actually read SGA 1, I would really like to hear what their opinion is on that. For example, is EGA in its entirety a prerequisite for SGA 1? And if not, what is really required for understanding this piece of work of Grothendieck?

Comment: If you are familiar with the basics of scheme theory (at least EGA I), I think it would be reasonable to just start reading SGA 1 and referring to the relevant chapters of EGA as necessary.

Comment: Also remark that chapter VI does not require scheme theory, only some basic category theory.

Comment: Don't read SGA or EGA as a textbook (this will take years), but rather use them as a reference work. That being said, the prerequisites are irrelevant.